# antd Calendar component can't load the correct style

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, antd

I tried to use  of antd in my component but it can't load the correct style.
This is my code:

```
import { Calendar } from 'antd';
<Box sx={{width:350, height:350}}>
  <Calendar fullscreen={true}/>
</Box>
```

This is its style in my component:
[In my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjVpz.png)

And this its correct component in the official document:
[In doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv3UC.png)

This is the link of official doc:https://ant.design/components/calendar/

Comment: They provide code and codesandbox demo, Did you checked?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like stylesheet not imported.
Please follow the [installation](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce#Installation) process

This should be work.

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; // or antd/dist/antd.less
```

Comment: I have tried import this stylesheet but it still doesn't work :-(

Comment: Are you using less or css?